# Rails console NameError: uninitialized constant - nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4 and simple form.

I have three models - Project, Project_Question and Project_Answer. I made all of these by generating scaffolds so all naming conventions have been followed.

My resources are nested:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

I am trying to use the console to find project answers created in my testing, but when I try to search for project answers:

```
2.1.1p76 :001 > Project_Answer.where(:answer => [hgvbhjb]).first
```

I get this error message:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Project_Answer, expected /app/models/project_answer.rb to define it.
```

The other problems on this site that seem to get the same error messages appear to be where people have not named their model.rb files in the singular. I have that.

I can only think that there is an extra step required to search the console if resources are nested. Does this sound plausible? If so, are there any materials to help figure out how to search the console with nested resources?

Can anyone see what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It should be

```
ProjectAnswer.where(:answer => "hgvbhjb").first
```

Comment: I tried ProjectAnswer.all and it puts a question mark into the terminal: 2.1.1p76 :008?>   ProjectAnswer.all

Comment: When I try: 2.1.1p76 :005 > ProjectAnswer.where(:answer => h), I get:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `h' for main:Object

Comment: @user2860931 I didn't get you. `:answer` is of what datatype?

Comment: it's a text attribute in the project_answer table

Comment: @user2860931 You should give it like `ProjectAnswer.where(:answer => "h")`